# Getting Epson Perfection V39 scanner to work in Arch?

Tags: arch-linux, software-installation, scanner

I'm trying to get Epson Perfection V39 scanner to work in Arch. It's USB scanner and gets power directly from USB port.

```
% sane-find-scanner
found USB scanner (vendor=0x04b8 [EPSON], product=0x013d [Epson Perfection V39]) at libusb:001:002
```

Trying scanimage:

```
% scanimage -L

No scanners were identified. If you were expecting something different,
check that the scanner is plugged in, turned on and detected by the
sane-find-scanner tool (if appropriate). Please read the documentation
which came with this software (README, FAQ, manpages).
```

lsusb:

```
% lsusb -v

Bus 001 Device 002: ID 04b8:013d Seiko Epson Corp. 
Device Descriptor:
  bLength                18
  bDescriptorType         1
  bcdUSB               2.00
  bDeviceClass          255 Vendor Specific Class
  bDeviceSubClass       255 Vendor Specific Subclass
  bDeviceProtocol       255 Vendor Specific Protocol
  bMaxPacketSize0        64
  idVendor           0x04b8 Seiko Epson Corp.
  idProduct          0x013d 
  bcdDevice            1.00
  iManufacturer           1 EPSON
  iProduct                2 Epson Perfection V39
  iSerial                 3 *censored*
  bNumConfigurations      1
  Configuration Descriptor:
    bLength                 9
    bDescriptorType         2
    wTotalLength           32
    bNumInterfaces          1
    bConfigurationValue     1
    iConfiguration          0 
    bmAttributes         0x80
      (Bus Powered)
    MaxPower              500mA
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        0
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           2
      bInterfaceClass       255 Vendor Specific Class
      bInterfaceSubClass    255 Vendor Specific Subclass
      bInterfaceProtocol    255 Vendor Specific Protocol
      iInterface              0 
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x81  EP 1 IN
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes
        bInterval             255
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x02  EP 2 OUT
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes
        bInterval             255
Device Qualifier (for other device speed):
  bLength                10
  bDescriptorType         6
  bcdUSB               2.00
  bDeviceClass          255 Vendor Specific Class
  bDeviceSubClass       255 Vendor Specific Subclass
  bDeviceProtocol       255 Vendor Specific Protocol
  bMaxPacketSize0        64
  bNumConfigurations      1
can't get debug descriptor: Resource temporarily unavailable
Device Status:     0x0000
  (Bus Powered)
```

http://www.sane-project.org/cgi-bin/driver.pl?manu=epson&model=perfection+v39&bus=any&v=&p= says: *supported by the **epkowa** backend plus non-free interpreter*.

There's also `.deb` and `.rpm` packages for various other distros but not for Arch here:

- http://support.epson.net/linux/en/imagescanv3.php?version=1.3.20
- http://support.epson.net/linux/en/iscan.php?model=gt-s650&version=1.0.1
- http://download.ebz.epson.net/dsc/du/02/DriverDownloadInfo.do?LG2=FI&CN2=&DSCMI=58068&DSCCHK=9d9059503419852a5e39de1187b54bbe7b95cea8
- http://download.ebz.epson.net/dsc/du/02/DriverDownloadInfo.do?LG2=FI&CN2=&DSCMI=47255&DSCCHK=40572accad406fe06a4d0808e8c615ebe1460de6

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found that this plugin works https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/iscan-plugin-gt-s650/

As root:

```
# pacman -S iscan iscan-data
```

As user:

```
% git clone https://aur.archlinux.org/iscan-plugin-gt-s650.git
% cd iscan-plugin-gt-s650
% makepkg
```

As root:

```
# pacman -U iscan-plugin-gt-s650-1.1.0-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz
```